# bt google maps not show in my website?

Tags: joomla-3.x

bt google maps module not show in my website? what is the problem? Thank you very much. [image][image]

Comment: What is the link to your site?

Comment: my website is 1psd.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use Helix regularly, but I believe the position name is position3 instead of position-3.  Try changing it to see if it appears.

Comment: thank you. I can put google map in my template but It is displayed in white?! why?  please go to http://1psd.net/index.php/contact

Comment: I am seeing a Google Maps API error.  It says you are missing your key.

Comment: With your help, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps.

1. Go to Menu Assignment tab on your module settings
2. Select "On All Pages" of Menu Assignment option.

Comment: Did not work :(